# Split one column into multiple

Tags: r

I have a dataframe

```
x  bookId  x1
1     412  action
2     454  action|adventure|comedy
3     413  comedy
```

I want to split the x1 column into as many required (I do not know the maximum values x1 takes in any particular row).

So the df would become

```
x  bookId  x1     x2        x3
1     412  action
2     454  action adventure comedy
3     413  comedy
```

I'm not sure how I should do this, can someone please point me in the right direction?

Comment: How do you load the data? read.csv ? If so, there is an option to use another separator instead of a comma.

Comment: I load the data in csv, the format is :

bookId, x1,
412, action|aventure|comedy

So my values are separated by commas, just the values inside this cell are using |

Comment: A simple way around would be to save to disk only the column you want separated and the reload it using | as separator and then join to the original

Comment: replace the the comma in csv file to "|"  then load the data using seperator "|"(pipe)